# Get radio buttons from enum in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to render radio buttons using an enumeration in my MVC2 application.

Can anybody help me out resolve this issue.

Thanks for sharing your wisdom.

Comment: @linkerro: I am not expert in MVC but was trying to use RadioButtonFor but it works only with single value, now i am trying to create my own extension to draw radio buttons using enum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use the GetNames function:

```
<% foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnumType)))
           {
               %>
                <input type="radio" value="<%=name %>" name="instanceName"/>
               <%

           } %>
```

then on the server side you can use Enum.Parse function to parse the string back into an enum.

UPDATE

Jace is correct to comment that the default model binder will map the string to the enum for you.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your quick reply.

Comment: The default model binding in MVC can parse the values back to enums. You should not need to call Enum.Parse on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use reflection. You get all the members of the enum, and for each you create an input element  but what you need to know is that the following code segment uses reflection to list all the elements in an enumeration.

```
    public enum JuiceTypes
    {
        Apple,
        Orange,
        Pineapple,
        Peach,
        HoneyTea,
        Tomato
    }

        string[] juiceTypes = Enum.GetNames(typeof(JuiceTypes));
        foreach (string juice in juiceTypes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(juice); 
            //in MVC you need to use Response.WriteLine("<input type=\"radio\" value=\"+juice+"\"/>");
        }
```